# specify different development and production tsconfig file in webpack depending on NODE_ENV

Tags: typescript, webpack, awesome-typescript-loader

I have two different files `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.prod.json` and I'm trying to switch between these depending on whether webpack is run in development or production mode (-d/-p).

Here is my attempt at a `webpack.config.js`, which doesn't work:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        background: './src/background.ts',
        popup: './src/popup.tsx',
        'content-script': './src/content-script.ts'
    },

    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve('extension-dist/js')
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
    },

    devtool: 'source-map',

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    configFile: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?
                        path.resolve('./tsconfig.prod.json') :
                        path.resolve('./tsconfig.json')
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development'
};
```

But I'm still seeing this output from typescript even when running in production mode:

> ℹ ｢atl｣: Using typescript@3.7.2 from typescript
>
> ℹ ｢atl｣: Using tsconfig.json from /twitter-extension/tsconfig.json